# VBA is not working in Excel 365 pro plus - 'pastespecial method of range class failed'

Tags: vba, excel, office365

The macro which is built on Excel 2007, takes too long run and finally displaying the error message

> "run-time error 1004 -- pastespecial method of range class failed".

Whereas the same macros works very well in Excel 2007, getting completed within 30 seconds without any error.

please check and advise.

Code Starts:

```
Sub Import()
    Dim SourceFile As Workbook
    Dim SourceTab As Worksheet
    Dim TargetTab As Worksheet

    SourceFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files ,     *.xlt;*.xls;*.xlsx;*.csv")

    If SourceFileName = False Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set TargetTab = Sheets("Output")
    TargetRow = TargetTab.Cells(TargetTab.Cells.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Set SourceFile = Workbooks.Open(SourceFileName)

    SourceFile.Activate
    Set SourceTab = Sheets("Sheet1")
    SourceTab.Activate

    For i = 1 To Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        If Len(Cells(i, 2).Value) = 2 Then

            Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 31).Value
            Cells(i, 31).Resize(1, 1).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Activate
            TargetTab.Activate
            Cells(TargetRow, 3).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            SourceFile.Activate

            Cells(i, 5).Value = Cells(i, 11).Value
            Cells(i, 11).Resize(1, 1).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Activate
            TargetTab.Activate
            Cells(TargetRow, 5).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            SourceFile.Activate

            Cells(i, 6).Value = Cells(i, 19).Value
            Cells(i, 19).Resize(1, 1).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Activate
            TargetTab.Activate
            Cells(TargetRow, 6).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            SourceFile.Activate

            Cells(i, 7).Value = Cells(i, 27).Value
            Cells(i, 27).Resize(1, 1).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Activate
            TargetTab.Activate
            Cells(TargetRow, 7).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            SourceFile.Activate

            Cells(i, 9).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value
            Cells(i, 4).Resize(1, 1).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Activate
            TargetTab.Activate
            Cells(TargetRow, 9).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            SourceFile.Activate

            Cells(i, 11).Value = Cells(4, 5).Value
            Cells(4, 5).Resize(1, 1).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Activate
            TargetTab.Activate
            Cells(TargetRow, 11).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            SourceFile.Activate

            Cells(i, 13).Value = Cells(2, 25).Value
            Cells(2, 25).Resize(1, 1).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Activate
            TargetTab.Activate
            Cells(TargetRow, 13).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            SourceFile.Activate

            Cells(i, 14).Value = Cells(i, 43).Value
            Cells(i, 43).Resize(1, 1).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Activate
            TargetTab.Activate
            Cells(TargetRow, 14).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            SourceFile.Activate

            Cells(i, 17).Value = Cells(i, 8).Value
            Cells(i, 8).Resize(1, 1).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Activate
            TargetTab.Activate
            Cells(TargetRow, 17).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            SourceFile.Activate

            TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
            'TargetNewRows = TargetNewRows + 1
        End If
    Next
    SourceFile.Close False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure this should take 30 seconds in Excel 2007... I'd start by using Worksheet and Workbook references and direct assignments instead of .Activate and the global objects.

Comment: Sir... to be frank ... i am very new to VBA... Not getting your answer at all...  Hence would you please let me know the exact place where i need to make what kind of changes..

Comment: Anyone would you please help me on this issue... its pretty urgent

Comment: See [Referring to Other Worksheets or Workbooks in an Excel Macro](http://ww2.cfo.com/spreadsheets/2011/08/referring-to-other-worksheets-or-workbooks-in-an-excel-macro/), [Workbook and Worksheet Object](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/workbook-worksheet-object.html) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

This type of thing:

```
Cells(i, 6).Value = Cells(i, 19).Value
     Cells(i, 19).Resize(1, 1).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        TargetTab.Activate
        Cells(TargetRow, 6).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        SourceFile.Activate
```

Would be better as:

```
SourceTab.Cells(i, 6).Value = SourceTab.Cells(i, 19).Value
TargetTab.Cells(TargetRow, 6).Value = SourceTab.Cells(i, 19).Value
```

skipping all of the Select/Activate calls, which are not required and make your code likely to fail unexpectedly.  You code should, wherever possible, not rely any any particular range, sheet or workbook being active/selected.